# Can't get rid of a ghost module

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pkg-resources

So this is a weird one...
I admit, I install my own module with a wild mix of

- python setup.py install
- python setup.py develop
- pip install .
- pip install -e .

but I cannot identify the source of a remaining ability to import my module (planet4) after having used 'pip uninstall' and manually removed any remaining eggs or egg-links, or even entries in *.pth files.

I tried the obvious: `planet4.__file__` but that's empty:

```
In [12]: planet4.__file__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-09c196cdfffe> in <module>()
----> 1 planet4.__file__

AttributeError: module 'planet4' has no attribute '__file__'
```

Python still thinks this is a module:

```
In [16]: type(planet4)
Out[16]: module
```

and when I try to use `pkg_resources` to get to some hidden file paths I get the weirdest error that even Google only has seen a couple of times, at least related to **removing** a package:

```
In [10]: import pkg_resources as pr
In [11]: pr.resource_exists('planet4', 'data')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-3ac559fe861b> in <module>()
----> 1 pr.resource_exists('planet4', 'data')

/Users/klay6683/miniconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-19.6.2-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resource_exists(self, package_or_requirement, resource_name)
   1137     def resource_exists(self, package_or_requirement, resource_name):
   1138         """Does the named resource exist?"""
-> 1139         return get_provider(package_or_requirement).has_resource(resource_name)
   1140
   1141     def resource_isdir(self, package_or_requirement, resource_name):

/Users/klay6683/miniconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-19.6.2-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py in has_resource(self, resource_name)
   1603
   1604     def has_resource(self, resource_name):
-> 1605         return self._has(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
   1606
   1607     def has_metadata(self, name):

/Users/klay6683/miniconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-19.6.2-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _has(self, path)
   1658     def _has(self, path):
   1659         raise NotImplementedError(
-> 1660             "Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type"
   1661         )
   1662

NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
```

Anybody has anymore ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a python prompt

```
import sys

for p in sys.path:
    print p
```

That will give you a list of directories.  Go look in all of them for a directory or file with the name `planet4`.  Also look for any `.pth` files.  If you find any, open them in a text editor, they will give you more directories to look in, rinse and repeat.

Comment: It was a lot in there, so I shied away from that first. But then I saw an unexpected folder in there and thought about my past experience with PYTHONPATH and investigated further. As I wrote in my post, I did check for .pth files.

Comment: I still give you the answer point, b/c at the end, this is the only way to really get down to the bottom of it, if the pointer to the module doesn't tell you anymore about itself.

Answer (score -1):

*groan*, so apparently, PYTHONPATH (which I did not use anymore since long) even creates entries in the module namespace for folders that do not have an `__init__.py` file inside.
So, not knowing that, plus the fact that I did not remember that I still had a PYTHONPATH environment variable defined, created the conundrum.

PYTHONPATH really IS the source of many evils... :(

**UPDATE**
So, while this entry is the answer why things went wrong in my specific case, the accepted answer is how I found it and how one would find it in similar cases: I looked at `sys.path` for anything fishy.

Comment: Best solution is to use a virtualenv and let setup.py handle the PYTHONPATH variable for you automatically. That way you don't have to handle it manually. You can also nuke the virtualenv and recreate quickly if something goes awry

Comment: I'm using virtualenvs but still had a PYTHONPATH set in an old .zshrc file that was loaded. Why the downvote? I correctly point out that PYTHONPATH setting is bad.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Someone else did. PYTHONPATH is awful I wholeheartedly agree.